# eclipse product export wizard - Messages while mirroring artifact descriptor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, osgi, product

I've got an Eclipse Product that I export to different operating systems using the 'eclipse product export wizard'

The application used to include javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar in the export but it no longer needs the jar.

The application runs perfectly without this jar but when I remove it from the pr

However if I remove it from the dependencies I get the follow exception

`C:\Users\Kris\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.p2.xml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Kris\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.p2.xml:127: Messages while mirroring artifact descriptors.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,javax.mail,1.4.0.v201005080615.
The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Kris\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.pde.core\temp\org.eclipse.pde.container.feature\assemble.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.p2.xml:127: Messages while mirroring artifact descriptors.
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,javax.mail,1.4.0.v201005080615.`

Its most annoying as I have no idea what it means?!

Then when I deploy the application I have to also delete this jar that is included in the export

Help, eeeeck!

Kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search through all of your plugins and feature projects to make sure "javax.mail" is not somewhere where you don't expect it. And also make sure you are exporting to a new directory (so that it's not finding anything else there).

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best. I did a search of all files for javax.mail and found one in a manifest file. Removed it and works fine. I guess this is a reason against coding at 2am :)